# Can I have colored filename without tabs in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently switched off tabs in IntelliJ to get peace of mind. Unfortunately the coloring of the filename is now partly lost. The foreground color still works as expected (turning edited files blue). But the Non-project files do not get the yellowich background as when using tabs.

Q: Is there a way to get the backgroundcolor to show without the tabs? Or could the information be presented in some other way (I know its visible in the filetree and various listing of files, but this is not what I'm after).

[image]

With tabs:

[image]

Without tabs:

[image]

Comment: I don't really get what you want. `File Color` is for files tree view, but since it's not what you want, than _what_ you want?